# Google Fit session not appearing in history

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to create a workout session using the Google Fit REST api and it's not appearing in the user's history on the Fit Android app.

I am following their guide [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/using-sessions) and using the OAuth playground [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) with the following steps:

1. I have granted access to the playground for `fitness.activity.read` and `fitness.activity.write` and obtained the necessary tokens
2. I'm making a call to `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions/example-fit-1411053997` with the following payload

```
{
  "id": "example-fit-1411053997",
  "name": "My example workout",
  "description": "A very intense workout",
  "startTimeMillis": 1396710000000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1396713600000,
  "version": 1,
  "lastModifiedToken": "exampleToken",
  "application": {
    "detailsUrl": "http://example.com",
    "name": "Foo Example App",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "activityType": 1
}
```

3. I can see a 200 response code meaning my session was created and I can confirm the session gets listed when I call `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions`
4. The session **doesn't** appear in the Google Fit mobile app for the same user account.

However, if I switch to a different user account on the device and switch back the session appears. This happens every time and I cannot make the session appear right away. I have also tried recording sessions from Android directly and those appear instantly in the Fit app. Am I missing extra steps necessary for the REST Api?

**Edit**

I tried the same on iOS and I can see my workout in the history. Could this be a bug on Android?

**Edit 2**

So I've tested on 3 devices - 2 androids and one iOS. iOS works as expected - all sessions are listed there and when I create a session from the Google Fit app it gets returned by the API.

However, on Android on both phones when I create sessions from the Fit app they don't even get sent it seems because I'm not receiving them from the Api. Definitely starting to look like a sync issue on their Android end.

Comment: Does it work if you connect your phone to a charger (charging on WiFi triggers a sync, I believe).

Comment: It worked the first time but the phone had been locked for a few mins. Subsequent attempts didn't work.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps they have something which detects the time spacing between activities and since I'm testing quite often maybe that blocks the requests behind the scenes? But I do have auto-detected sessions from a few days ago that don't sync so maybe not...